# If integration sends the space of all rational functions to the same space union $\ln x$, where does integration send $\mathbb Q[x,\ln x]$?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

***If integration sends the space of all rational functions to the same space union $\ln x$, where does integration send $\mathbb Q[x,\ln x]$?***

For example, if I have any rational function, which can be written as a sum

$$Q(x)=\sum_n \left(\frac{C_n}{x-\rho_n}+a_nx^n\right),$$ I'm bound to get another rational function, or in the specific case of $(1/x)$, some $\ln x$ term. Once I have the logarithm, I can construction functions in the space $\mathbb Q[x,\ln x],$ in the sense that if any $F$ belonging to the space can be written

$$F(x)=\frac{\sum_n a_nx^n+b_n(\ln x)^n}{\sum_k c_kx^k+d_k(\ln x)^k},$$ which I can then integrate and obtain a new novel function which needs closed form $$\int\frac{1}{\ln x}dx,$$ and so on. Am I right to think that there is a closed form for any $n$th integral of a rational function if I include the following sequence of functions in my space:

$$\int \frac{1}{x}dx, \ \int\frac{1}{\int \frac{1}{x}dx}dx, \ \int \frac{1}{\int \frac{1}{\int \frac{1}{x}dx}dx}dx, \text{etc} ?$$

---

I want to clarify a few points for the commenters:

I apologize for not specifying, I am aware. By integrating rational functions we obtain $\ln x$ *up to linear substitutions*, which I don't care much for. I want to think about this in the sense that "I integrated rational functions, and I found out about this new function $\ln$, which I can compose my rational functions with. Now I wonder how many more functions I need to write $n$th integrals of $\mathbb Q[x]$ in closed form."

Also, what I'm asking is, for example, can we integrate an arbitrary function in $\mathbb Q[x,\ln x]$, in the sense above, and write it in rational functions of

$$x,\ \lambda_1(x)=\ln |x|,\ \lambda_2(x) =\int^x\frac{1}{\ln |\chi|}d\chi$$

Comment: You don't *just* get $\ln x$ when integrating rational functions, but things like $\ln(x-a)$ when you integrate $1/(x-a)$.  So integrating rational functions leads to something much larger than $\mathbf Q[x,\ln x]$ or even $\mathbf R[x,\ln x]$. By the way, there is no "closed form" for $\int dx/\ln x$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same space union $\ln x$"?  You need to allow $\ln(x-r)$ for all complex constants $r$

Comment: $ \int \frac{dx}{\ln(x)} = \mathrm{Ei}\! \left(\ln \! \left(x \right)\right)$: a "closed form", but not elementary.

Comment: On the other hand, $\int \frac{dx}{x+\ln(x)}$ seems not to have a closed form.

Comment: And you do get this that are not logarithms from integrating rational functions, like inverse trigonometric functions.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Those inverse trig functions can be expressed using (complex) logarithms: $$\arctan(x) = \frac{\mathrm{i}}{2} \left(\ln \! \left(1-\mathrm{i} x \right)-\ln \! \left(1+\mathrm{i} x \right)\right)$$

Comment: But here the coefficients are real, even rational, afaict.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'm allowing complex numbers, yes.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad then clearly you should edit your question to reflect this, don't you think?